# Как узнать, применяется ли схемы оформления (Vcl.Styles)?

Tags: delphi, vcl

D 10.1 starter. Стандартное приложение. В опциях включены схемы оформления.
Вопрос: Как программно узнать, применяется ли сейчас какая-то схема оформления или стиль оформления стандартный?

если схема применяется, то в файле проекта видим (например):

```
...
TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Amethyst Kamri'); *
...
```

если в опциях проекта схемы выбраны, но дефолтное оформление выбрано "Windows", то в проекте ничего (*) такого нет

Нужна функция примерно такая

```
Function IsAppThemed:boolean;
begin
 Result := <..?..>
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел:

```
function IsAppThemed: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TStyleManager.Enabled and TStyleManager.IsCustomStyleActive;
end;
```

Comment: спасибо за правку