# Непонятные размеры окон при Vcl.Styles - win & other

Tags: delphi, vcl

[Начало вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677043/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-vcl-styles)

Начало (ну или будет полезен) вопроса выше, по ссылке, ничего примечательного. 
Тема такая:

D 10.1 starter. Стандартное приложение. В опциях включены схемы оформления. 
Теперь определения, применяется ли схема оформления или нет - берем оттуда, те же функции.

Снова (при выборе других тем оформления в опциях проекта), выбираю стиль умолчальный - Windows. Т.е. другие присутствуют, пока не выберутся программно, но дефолтный стиль есть - Windows.

Все работает нормально. Для всех стилей. Кроме умолчального - Windows.
При его выборе (во всяком случае у мну) -............. вернее не так, при разработке по умолчанию в этом стиле все ок. А как только задействую любой другой - наблюдается небольшой **косяк в правой стороне приложения - оно примерно на 5-10 пикселей всегда меньше (и если запускать с новой схемой оформления, то правая сторона всех форм - как правило меньше, чем в оригинале)**.

Борюсь так (костыли)

```
Procedure GuNewRForm;
GuAddRighForm=8; // экспериментально методом тыка
Var i:integer;
begin
if not GuIsAppThemed then exit;
for i:=0 to application.ComponentCount-1 do
if (application.Components[i] is TForm) then With TForm(application.Components[i]) Do width:=width+GuAddRightForm;
end;

Function GuIsAppThemed:boolean;
begin
if (TStyleManager.Enabled)and(TStyleManager.IsCustomStyleActive) then result:=true else result:=false;
end;

Function GuGetRForm:integer;
begin
if GuIsAppThemed then result:=GuAddRightForm else result:=0;
end;
```

и в файле проекта перед application.run; добавляю GuNewRForm; {из отдельного модуля, кот. в uses 1й}

Вопросы:

1. Почему возникает разница в правых полях!? (Я ранее читал про DPI, scaled form и др, но не на столько же!)
2. Как с этим бороться?
3. Как правильно рассчитать разницу между [win.view.formwith] & [themed.view.formwith]? пока только на глаз.
4. Может е проще способ и я все усложняю?

   ++ если непонятно написал, предоставлю код и более подробное описание

Comment: границы окна скорее всего в стандартной теме есть, а при использовании стилей граница убирается.

Comment: обратите внимание на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446827/vcl-styles-client-size-of-form-reduced), например, и решения которые там предложены.

Comment: 2 teran, спасибо за внимание. но все формы при созданиии у мну scaled=false (обратное пробовал), не помогает.+ нашел кучу инфы в инете на эту тему, но ни одна не объясняет, почему так + конкретно расчеты. вернее почему - объ. е, а вот как найти разницу, что больше акт. для мну - нет.

Comment: оптимальным ответом считал бы нахождение разницы между стилями+почему она возникает\или как сделать все одинаковым\или "правильный путь".

Comment: да вроде по приведенной мной ссылке, товарищ RRUZ, разработчик Delphi IDE theme editor и всяких таких утилит, написал, что разница возникает из за того, что разные стили имеют разную ширину границы. Там же написано, что есть косяк с тем, что делфи не корректно восстанавливает ClientWIdth из dfm,

Comment: возможно, но там так и не нашел формулы (слаб в анг.) + вам спасибо, что правили мои вопросы. там е. объяснение (на сколько языка хватает), но нет расчетов - как получить разность.

Comment: ++ может зря привязался я к этому значению? может есть выход лучше?

Comment: еще интересно другое - все крассиво, кроме правой сторону всех форм. вот она меньше становится. костыли выше демонстрировал, но почему именно правая сторона + все обсуждения выше... неясно

Answer (score 1):

При применении тем, всегда сохраняется размер клиентской области - а границы у разных стилей имеют свои размеры.